# Не переходит на страницу с русскими буквами в URL

Tags: url, кириллица

Подскажите пожалуйста. Заказчик хочет, чтобы *URL* были с кириллицей, и заказал домен `.рф`.

Столкнулся с проблемой, что некоторые страницы не открывает. В хостинге написали, что в названии присутствуют дополнительные символы.

Как увидеть эти символы или как решить проблему с кириллицей в *URL*?

Comment: Можно ссылку на страницу, которую не открывает?

Comment: Уже все работает, через ssh подключился и проверил названия страниц, перед разрешением был символ "?". Через файловый менеджер хостинга удалил название, и руками его вновь переименовал и заработало